# Need to run twice in-order for it to fully work

Tags: php

```
$find = '.5010.';
$directory_with_files = './'.date('m-d-Y');
$dh  = opendir($directory_with_files);
$files = array();
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
{
if(in_array($filename, array('.', '..')) || is_dir($filename))
continue;

$files[] = $filename;}

foreach($files as $file){
//find only 5010 files
if(stripos($file, $find) !== false){
// open the 5010 file
$handle = fopen(date('m-d-Y').'/'.$file, "r");
$file_content = file_get_contents(date('m-d-Y').'/'.$file);
$handle2 = fopen(date('m-d-Y').'/'.$file, "r");
$file_content2 = file_get_contents(date('m-d-Y').'/'.$file);

if ($handle) {
$header = '';
$name = '';
$footer = '';
$payor_blocks = array();


// determine if file has more than one payor
$payor_count = substr_count($file_content, 'N1*PR*');
//if the file has more than one payor
if($payor_count > 1) {
//read the file line by line
$header_end = false;
$block_start = false;
$count = 1;


if($handle2){
$line_number = 0;
$line_stop= array();
while (($line1 = fgets($handle2)) !== false) {

$line_number++;

if(strpos($line1, 'CAS') !==false){

$line_stop[] = $line_number;}}
$footer_line = count($line_stop)-2;
$footer_line = $line_stop[$footer_line];              
$line_number = 0; }

//look for occurances of CAS and what line each on is on

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
$line_number++;

//look for the first payor block
if(strpos($line, 'N1*PR*') !== false || $block_start) {
$header_end = true; $block_start = true;
if(strpos($line, 'N1*PR*') !== false) {
$count++;
}  

//see if the block finished
if($line_number == $footer_line) {
$block_start = false;
$payor_blocks[$count] .= $line;
$count++; }
$payor_blocks[$count] .= $line;} 
else {
if($header_end) {
$footer .= $line."\n";  }
else {
$header .= $line."\n";}}

$refid = 'REF*2U*';

if(stripos($line, $refid) !== false)
{
$refnumber = str_replace(array($refid, '~'), array('', ''), $line);
$refnumber = trim($refnumber);

if($refnumber != '')
{
$refnumber = '_'.$refnumber.'_';
$filerenamed = str_replace($find, $refnumber,$file);
copy('./'.date('m-d-Y').'/'.$file, './'.date('m-d-Y').'/'. $filerenamed);
}
echo $refnumber . "\n";

}
}
//get payor blocks and create a file foreach payor
$new_files = array();
foreach($payor_blocks as $block) {
$filename = date('m-d-Y').'/'.$file . "_" . $count;
$count++;
$new_files[] = array(
'name' => $filename,
'content' => $header."\n".$block."\n".$footer   

);

}

foreach($new_files as $new_file) {

$myfile = fopen($new_file['name'], "w");

fwrite($myfile, $new_file['content']);  

fclose($myfile);
}

} 

else{

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
{
$refid = 'REF*2U*';

if(stripos($line, $refid) !== false)
{
$refnumber = str_replace(array($refid, '~'), array('', ''), $line);
$refnumber = trim($refnumber);

if($refnumber != '')
{
$refnumber = '_'.$refnumber.'_';
$filerenamed = str_replace($find, $refnumber,$file);
copy('./'.date('m-d-Y').'/'.$file, './'.date('m-d-Y').'/'. $filerenamed);
}
echo $refnumber . "\n";

}

}
}
}

}
// DONE - close the file
fclose($handle);
}

foreach($files as $fiftyfile){
if(stripos($fiftyfile, $find) !== false){

$handle3 = fopen(date('m-d-Y').'/'.$fiftyfile, "r");
$file_content3 = file_get_contents(date('m-d-Y').'/'.$fiftyfile);

if ($handle3) {
if(unlink('./'.date('m-d-Y').'/'.$fiftyfile))
{
echo "file named $fiftyfile has been deleted successfully";
}
else
{
echo "file is not deleted";
}
}
}

}
```

I have a few files in my directory with filenames that contain "3256.5010.548674.23a" In this code it opens the file and searches if there is more than one "N1*PR*" and if there is to split them into separate files. Lastly to change ".5010." to the REF number which is something like "*8743*" . Then it deletes all the files with ".5010." And combines the rest in one document. It works fine however, when I first run it it splits and renames, but only deletes the first files not all the ".5010." (not the ones that were split), which then when I run it again after that, it deletes everything but renames the old ones, since it goes through the "else statement" that also does the renaming. How could I solve the issue with the delete?

Comment: Can you take some time to edit your code with readable indentation between `{}` and trim it down to only the parts most relevant to your issue? There is too much right now, and none of it is laid out in a way that makes it possible to scan and understand

Comment: I tried to edit now as much as I can to make it understandable the problem is, when I dont post the whole code, users want it all so they could see all the variables and I guess I could remove some, but im not sure if the code will make sense after, would you like me too? @MichaelBerkowski